# Unsafe code to change length (by mutation!) of a String object?

Tags: c#, .net, string, unsafe

As .NET doesn't use C style `null`s to end a string how can I keep the allocated string but change the length of it by using unsafe code?

As I understand .NET using a 20 bytes header for every string, presumably this is where the length of the string is stored, is there anyway to directly modify this length? So .NET will keep the string in memory but when I call `.Length` it'll return the `.Length` I want.

*if this is possible, also it would be interesting to hear all crazy possible side-effects of this*

**UPDATE**

I'm trying  accomplish this without using reflection.

Comment: Note that .Net strings are null-terminated.

Comment: What do you need to do THAT for?

Comment: @jacob some evil experiment about memory management :) Trying allocate one large chunk of memory and reuse it constantly without to avoid LOH fragmentation.

Comment: @SLaks I know but adding a null byte to middle of a string will not change how it's treated as null character .NET strings is treated as any other character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Strings UNDOCUMENTED](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/strings.aspx)

```
public static unsafe void SetLength(string s, int length)
{
    fixed(char *p = s)
    {
        int *pi = (int *)p;
        if (length<0 || length > pi[-2])
            throw( new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length") );
        pi[-1] = length;
        p[length] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the string class has changed substantially in .Net 4; it now only has two fields.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for, I'll test this now

Comment: Is there any article around for .NET 4.0 updates related to `System.String` updates?

Comment: Works perfectly as expected, now I wonder what awkward problems I'm going to have :)

Comment: @dr. evil I'm sure there will be a painful "it doesn't work" session for some poor replacement in the future when you're long gone as soon as .NET xyz rolls-around or it's used on an alternate run-time (Mono?) or a non-x86/64 .NET or ... At least, hopefully it's a replacement and not you by that time ;-)

Comment: @pst Sure it'll fail in some places but just for the records it works in .NET 4.0 and x64

Comment: @dr. evil Which is neat, but "how much does it really gain"? There are a number of approaches to this problem, I'm sure. This is sort of an ... evil one :) Poor interned string or strings used in a hash or ... YMMV for sure.

Comment: @pst unfortunately there isn't, pretty much only real solution to this problem is restarting your application. Please tell me if you know a solution to LOH Fragmentation, because seems like no one got a solution to it. The question is how can you allocate thousands of large strings without causing LOH Fragmentation?

Comment: @pst take a look at this question which is related with I'm trying to accomplish : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020550/regex-stringbuilder-and-large-object-heap-fragmentation

Comment: @dr.evil - I work on complex Windows client apps that juggle lots of data and can run for days. I haven't needed to hack .NET to get them to work. That said, since you have experienced issues, perhaps .NET is not the right platform for your needs.

Comment: @TrueWill Maybe it's maybe it's not, but guess what rewriting 10 year man day code in C++ is harder than hacking .NET to fix one problem.

Comment: Nice!  This helped me save an extra memory copy on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368176/2352507  (obviously this is "unsafe" but users should be reminded every time because of having to use the "unsafe" keyword)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to set the `m_StringLength` field.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say I'm trying to this unsafe code directly and not with reflection, updated the question.